# Spray routing, controllers and DAOs -- which should create Futures?

Tags: scala, future, spray

I'm using spray-routing. My router calls out to Controllers, which call out to DAOs. Which should create the Futures that are returned to the spray-can server? My thoughts are:

- The DAOs should return Futures, because that's where the long-running operation (the database query) happens
- The router should create Futures, to leave the most flexibility in when they are created

In the latter case, it would be possible to have a single future that makes multiple database queries without having to chain them.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are all requests to your router async? This might also be another bottle-neck(in terms of requests). What if each request was async and returned a future...

Comment: Yes, spray-can makes async requests to the router (as messages to an actor).